Charts are not showing all the data
My charts are only displaying the first pair of values in the database when there are multiple students. I know that the sql query is correct and that the correct values are being stored in the variables for each iteration of the while loop.
This function is called in 2 button click events.
private void addChartValues()
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = LoginSignUpForm.CreateConnection();
    SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT StudentAccounts.Username, DeckStats.CurrentStreak, DeckStats.HighestStreak, DeckStats.NumDaysAttempted, DeckStats.FlashcardsCreatedNum, DeckStats.OverdueCardNum FROM DeckStats INNER JOIN FlashcardDecks ON DeckStats.DeckID = FlashcardDecks.DeckID INNER JOIN Classes ON FlashcardDecks.ClassID = Classes.ClassID INNER JOIN StudentAccounts ON FlashcardDecks.StudentID = StudentAccounts.StudentID WHERE Classes.ClassName = '{SelectClassChartCmbBx.Text}'";
    SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    string username;
    int currentStreak;
    int HighestStreak;
    int NumOfDaysAttempted;
    int FlashcardsCreatedNum;
    int OverdueCardNum;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        username = reader.GetString(0);
        currentStreak = reader.GetInt32(1);
        HighestStreak = reader.GetInt32(2);
        NumOfDaysAttempted = reader.GetInt32(3);
        FlashcardsCreatedNum = reader.GetInt32(4);
        OverdueCardNum = reader.GetInt32(5);
        CurrentStreakChart.Series["Current Streak"].Points.AddXY(username, currentStreak);
        HighestStreakChart.Series["Highest Streak"].Points.AddXY(username, HighestStreak);
        NumAttemptedChart.Series["Number of Days Attempted"].Points.AddXY(username, NumOfDaysAttempted);
        CardsCreatedChart.Series["Number of Cards Created"].Points.AddXY(username, FlashcardsCreatedNum);
        OverdueCardsChart.Series["Number of Overdue Cards"].Points.AddXY(username, OverdueCardNum);
    }

    reader.Close();

    conn.Close();
}

I tried using breakpoints to inspect the values of the variables, but I'm not sure how to see the values of the charts to check if they are being added.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver16

I'd strongly suggest you use Dapper.
